# Image of house being repaired via optimization (FindMinimum) example in documentation?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, image-processing

In Mathematica's documentation, I recall seeing an example where a noisy image of a house was repaired using an optimization method (possibly FindMinimum) with a very large number of parameters (one per pixel).

Does anyone else recall seeing this example? And can you give me a pointer to it? I've reviewed the various optimization tutorials/guides but can't locate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexOptimization.html) then Applications -> ImageProcessing.

Comment: Thanks so much. For anyone else, direct link to example is https://wolfram.com/xid/0dcz7l4qtz8i-0szo9